# Player icon stuck in the same position on skyrim map

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was playing Skyrim and I tried to go to a quest but I could not find it because my player icon was stuck in the same position no matter where I go. I already tried to go back to another save but the icon stays the same. I also tried to fast travel some where else it moved to where I fast travel but if I walk around it stays in the same place.

Comment: Do you have any mods installed?

Comment: Yes Immersive Citizens - AI Overhaul,Realistic Water Two,Cheat Room and Necromancer Lord Armor.

Answer (score 2):

Update cheat room. There is a new cheat room update. I updated and my character icon is just fine an moves around it should help.

Comment: worked for other places but still doesn't work in riften of whiterun

Comment: Did you try disabling any mods

Comment: yes i tried everything

Comment: did you try restarting you game?

Comment: yes multiple times